# Reformulation of Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I **do** understand how we obtain the Fourier Transform

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) e^{-i \omega \xi} d \xi \; e^{i \omega x} d \omega.$$

However, in many textbooks I see that this should be equivalent to

$$f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\xi) e^{-i 2 \pi \omega \xi} d \xi \; e^{i 2 \pi \omega x} d \omega,$$

which I **do not** understand. I guess this is something very simple, but I do not get there. Could someone please guide me through the math step by step?

Comment: Just substitute $\omega \rightarrow 2\pi \omega$. Then $d\omega \rightarrow 2\pi d\omega$, canceling out the $2\pi$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Of course, a simple change of variables does the trick. I did not realize that $2 \pi \omega$ must be substituted for in two spots (inner and outer integral), so I was confused about the inner integral.

Comment: More generally the Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms can be defined as $F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2 \pi)^{1-a}}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\, e^{i b t \omega} \, dt$ and $f(t)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}[F(\omega)](t)=\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2 \pi)^{a+1}}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)\, e^{-i b t \omega} \, d\omega$ (see formulas 15 and 16 at [Wolfram MathWorld: Fourier Transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html)).